# Kendo UI listview doesn't connect with template

Tags: javascript, listview, kendo-ui

I created this very simple JSfiddle to find some help. I actually try to connect some data from a Kendo datasource to a listview. I simplified the example very much to get some help with the basic: http://jsfiddle.net/5J3z5/25/.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
data: [
    { id : 1 },
    { id : 2 }
    ]
});

$("#listView").kendoListView({
dataSource: dataSource,
template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
});
```

I only try to display the id's in the list and I really can't find where i do go wrong. Help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jsFiddle has an extra ';':

```
{ id : 2 };
```

Here is a working version of your simplified demo: http://jsbin.com/unEPAwAn/1/edit

Comment: Thanks. Eventhough it won't work with JSfiddle if i delete the ;. But seems to work fine on JSbin.

Comment: Yeah. For some reason it didn't work in jsFiddle for me either. That's why I tested in jsbin.